# What's the simplest way in Python to detect the time placement of individual audio files over a longer sequence?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, detection

So something that really bugs me about the DAW Ableton Live is that it cannot export MIDI files with tempo, meaning it's impossible to create an exportable tempo map for a song that changes speed throughout. But I am able to easily sequence a "metronome" sample myself and render that out as an audio file.

So what I'd like to do is to feed this long rendered metronome wave file in, alongside the short sample of the metronome, find the placement of every click, and then auto generate a midi track with bpm and time sig changes interpreted from the file.

Right now, my dumb approach is just to scan for the first non-zero sample, create the event, wait for another zero sample, and repeat until the file is fully read. This works ok because the input is silence inter-spliced with clicks, BUT it'd be nicer if I could detect different sounds that represent measure start or an eighth note division so I can also properly detect meter.

Any thoughts on the simplest way to do this with minimal imports? Just want a lightweight script with minimal dependencies to make clone hero charts.

Comment: I am not sure if I got right what is needed, but [aubio](https://aubio.org/) could be a good fit. It provides algorithms for tempo detection and note annotation.

Comment: find peaks of correlation between metronome signal and your recording

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the signal processing technique called *correlation*, as dankal444 mentioned. Calculating the correlation of two signals will create a new signal that has peaks where the two signals match. Here is an example using  scipy and numpy.

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

# TODO: - load sound signal and metronome sample as numpy arrays
#       - specify sample_rate
#       - tune detection_threshold

def find_clicks (sound, metronome_sample, sample_rate, detection_threshold):
    # Correlate the sound with the metronome sample
    corr_full = signal.correlate(sound, metronome_sample)
    # Remove backward correlated sound
    corr = corr_full[len(corr_full)//2:]

    # Find the peaks using the find_peaks algorithm
    # Specify a minimum height that the peaks must be above with "detection_threshold"
    peaks, properties = signal.find_peaks(corr, height=detection_threshold)
    # "peaks" will contain the placement of every click in sample count

    # Calculate the mean distance between each peak to find the period
    period = np.mean([peaks[i + 1] - peaks[i] for i in range(len(peaks) -1)])

    # BPM [beat/m]: sample rate [S/s] * 60 / ( period [S/beat])
    bpm =  sample_rate * 60/period

    return peaks, bpm
```